# nginx access log does not indicate GET or POST for some entries

Tags: nginx, python-requests

I'm getting log entries in access.log without the GET or POST indication.

For example:

```
<ip_addr> - - [27/Jan/2024:07:06:39 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*<snip>Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

I've been trying to recreate these requests using Python. When I do, the test system I use is reporting a different log entry:

```
<ip_addr> - - [02/Feb/2024:00:03:16 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0"
```

- I convert the log entry from "\x03..." to a bytearray called url
- I'm assuming it is a POST and so I use requests.post(svrname, data=url)
- requests.get() won't let me send these bytearray()s

I have tried sending the string from the log entry without converting to a bytearray.
That doesn't replicate the same log entry I'm seeing in the production system

```
<ip_addr> - - [02/Feb/2024:00:20:37 +0000] "GET /%5Cx03%5Cx00%5Cx00<snip>Cookie:%20mstshash=Administr HTTP/1.1" 502 190 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0"
```

i.e. it shows up as a "GET" and the rest of the log entry does not match either.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: If you log format is configured to log request methods, and you see neither of the ones well known, then it simply means that it is neither GET nor POST. you don't need to force it to show you some expected requested method. It means most likely a malformed request, e.g. HTTP accessed as HTTPS or vice versa.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I figured out what this. These guys are sending raw data over a socket. I was able to replicate that with python. The question now, is how should I handle that? 
https://serverfault.com/questions/1152890/nginx-config-for-binary-requests-on-port-80-or-443

Comment: I think we can't solve all the bad clients on the Internet, if there's too much log noise, just block those in the firewall I think.

Answer (score 0):

These requests are raw data being sent over a socket. The content is not formatted according to HTTP, and so nginx reports the content and sets the status code to 400.

I was able to replicate these with python.

I created another question in serverfault to see if there is an appropriate way to deal with them, other than letting nginx issues a 400 status code.

[https://serverfault.com/questions/1152890/nginx-config-for-binary-requests-on-port-80-or-443]

Note: this answer
[https://serverfault.com/questions/1144020/what-causes-an-apache-400/1144032#1144032] explains what these guys are trying to do:

- "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xfc\x01" which in this example is caused by trying to establish a TLS 1.2 connection on the plain HTTP port 80 (or any other port, even 443, when no TLS is configured there)
- "\x16\x03\x01 is a similar TLS 1 / 1.1 handshake
- \x16\x03" is a similar SSL3 handshake